# Foundation datepicker restricted date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, zurb-foundation

Hi guys i am using the foundation datepicker this one below:

http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example.html

Now at the moment it loads up the present date but i want it to load up a hard coded date i.e. year 2000 instead of year 2015. As i am using it for people to stat there date of birth therefore i don't want it showing 2015 at the start.

There is no point me posting my foundation-datepicker code on here as most developers would of heard of it + it is open source.

If anyone can help and point to me to where i can change this it be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `data-date` attribute - there are examples on the plugin page:

```
<a href="#" class="button small" id="dp5" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="2012-02-25">Change</a>
```